# Add hyperlink with trailing slash with jquery trashes the hyperlink closing tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do this:

```
$(selector).append("<li><a href=" + url + ">" + title + "</a></li>");
```

Its rendered as:

```
</a><//a>
```

My main question is why is that?

My side question is it safe to just remove the last char if its a `'/'`

Comment: could you produce a replicable example of this, maybe as a snippet or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any quotes around the generated href. A bare url may naturally contain a `/a` or something which could be parsed as closing your `<a>` tag.

```
$(selector).append("<li><a href=\"" + url + "\">" + title + "</a></li>");
                                ^^-----------^^
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really quote your href attribute value

```
$(selector).append("<li><a href=\"" + url + "\">" + title + "</a></li>");
```

the slash at the end is closing the `<a/>` tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with your quotes.

```js
var url = 'http://stackoverflow.com',
    title = 'Stackoverflow';

$('.example').append('<li><a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a></li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example"></div>
```